# Extracting characters every 2000 characters and save files

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I need to make an input for a program, which is really out of my skills in programming, that is why I haven't tried anything. Hope you can help me out.

I have lots of text files, beginning with the sign ">" a sample name, a line break, and then data in 0s and 1s, for every sample.

The data looks like this (much bigger actually):

```
 >SampleName_ZN189A
 01000001000000000000100011100000000111000000001000
 00110000100000000000010000000000001100000010000000
 00110000000000001110000010010011111000000100010000
 00000110000001000000010100000000010000001000001110
 >SampleName_ZN189B
 00110000001101000001011100000000000000000000010001
 00010000000000000010010000000000100100000001000000
 00000000000000000000000010000000000010111010000000
 01000110000000110000001010010000001111110101000000
```

**Note: After every 50 characters there is a line break.**

What I need to do is:

Extract the first 2000 characters of data of every sample in my file and save it with the same name followed by a window number. For example if this file was named: Testfile_1.txt it should look like this (I extracted the first 50 characters of data):

```
 >SampleName_ZN189A
 01000001000000000000100011100000000111000000001000
 >SampleName_ZN189B
 00110000001101000001011100000000000000000000010001
```

And this file should be named like this: Testfile_1_window1.txt

Now, the second window should begin from the character 1500 to the character 3500, that would be Testfile_1_window2.txt, the third file from character 3000 to 5000 name Testfile_1_window3.txt and so on... but if the last window has less than 2000 characters these characters should be added to the last window.

That is, by windows of 2000 characters with an overlap of 500 characters.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE2:**

If you think this problem could be solved using perl or python please post your answer also.

Comment: If extracting first 2000 characters then how come 2nd file `rom the character 1500 to the character 3500,`?

Comment: Overlap i would guess.

Comment: Yes, I need to extract the data of every sample every 2000 characters with an overlap of 500. This is why the first window will be from position 0 to 2000, the next window from 1500 to 3500, and so on.

Comment: 'if the last window has less than 2000 characters' not clear what you are saying here; do you mean if there are say 3300 characters, all 3300 go in the first window (because there aren't enough for a full second window?)

Comment: yes, exactly that. I prefer a solely window of 2000+ than two windows one with 2000 and the other with only 300 characters for example

Comment: For others' interest, you can do this on Linux with the command `split -b 2000 doc.txt`

Answer (score 1):

in Perl you could do this, it is looks like not so effective, but it could work because the op system will cache the file.

```
use strict;use warnings;
local $/='>';
open(my $fh,'<','filename') or die $!;    
while (my $chunk = <$fh>){
    chomp($chunk);
    $chunk =~ s!^(.+?)\n+!!is;
    my $samplename = $1;
    ### how many should be a constant or should be calculated on the fly, currently I set it to 50
    for(my $i=0;$i<50;$i++){        
        my $data = substr($chunk,$i*1500,$i*1500+2000);
        next if ! $data;##skip if there is not data
        my $filename = "Testfile_".$samplename."_window".$i.".txt";
        open(my $ofh,'>',$filename) or die $filename,$!;
        print $ofh "<$samplename\n$data\n";
        close($ofh);
    }
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: Nice solution. But i believe you forgot a `>` to append when you open `$ofh` or you will end with only the window from the last chunk. Also, i am not sure if op wanted newlines to be removed. But i may be wrong there, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I tried running it but got this error:Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at sites_window.pl line 11

Comment: I had a typo in the for loop, pls try again

Comment: @DeVadder: Because of $i the filename is going to be uniq

Comment: @user1126070 Ah sorry, i had in fact missed the `$samplename`, not the `$i` but you are still right, of course. From the question i had assumed the op wanted just one file per window, containing the data from that window from all samples instead of one file per window AND sample. But that propably does not matter all that much and would easily be adjustable, if i understood it right. Either way, i really like your solution and i doubt there is a much more efficient one. After all, you only read and loop everything once.